# Fatal error when altering the user login form

Tags: theming, blocks, users

i want to customize login block in a fancy login box.

i used this code in a template.php

```
function bootstrap_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['name']['#size'] = 30;
  $form['pass']['#size'] = 30;
  $markup = l(t('Forgot your password?'), 'user/password', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Request new password via e-mail.'))));
  if (variable_get('user_register', USER_REGISTER_VISITORS_ADMINISTRATIVE_APPROVAL)) {
    $markup .= ' ' . l(t('Sign up'), 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Create a new user account.'), 'class' => 'register-link')));
  }
  $markup = '<div class="clearfix">' . $markup . '</div>';
  $form['links']['#markup'] = $markup;
  $form['links']['#weight'] = 10000;
}
```

this code working fine, but on clicking singup link it giving error

> Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\common.inc on line 2445

How do I resolve it?

Comment: If you get this error _after_ clicking the link, then obviously the code you've posted has nothing to do with the error. You're probably altering the login process incorrectly somewhere else.

Comment: i have used logintoboggan module, does it affects anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is your class definition.

['attributes']['class'] should be an array but you are setting it as a string.

Your line:

```
$markup .= ' ' . l(t('Sign up'), 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Create a new user account.'), 'class' => 'register-link')));
```

Should be:

```
$markup .= ' ' . l(t('Sign up'), 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Create a new user account.'), 'class' => array('register-link'))));
```